# Get variable value from supplied js page in the console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nightmare

Let me explain what is the issue.

I am new here so please ignore my mistakes. I will try my best to explain myself.

I am having a webpage.html and I included a js script like from script or may be inside `<script>` tag.

I saved something like `var v ="my variable from a text box"` inside the webpage.

Now I want the var `v` value from the console to view the value of it.

I tried:

```
nightmare.evaluate(function () {
// now we're executing inside the browser scope.
return window.YOUR_VARIABLE;
}).then(function(YOUR_VARIABLE) {
// use the value
})
```

Did not worked for me.

The javascript is loading during the using process in webpage
and the script is :

```
initAvlFareEnq(e) {
                var t = 0;
                (Array.isArray(e.avlFareResponseDTO) ? e.avlFareResponseDTO : Array.of(e.avlFareResponseDTO)).forEach(e=>{
                    if (null == e.errorMessage && null == e.errorMessage) {
                        e.avlDayList = Array.isArray(e.avlDayList) ? e.avlDayList : Array.of(e.avlDayList);
                        
                        this.multiLapJourneyDetails.lapDetails.push(i)
                    } else
                        this.messageService.add({
                            life: this.langService.life,
                        })
                }
                ),
                this.multiLapJourneyDetails.mainJourneyTxnId = this.jpInput.txnId,
                this.multiLapJourneyDetails.clientTxnId = (new Date).getTime().toString(36),
                
            }
```

**I want this.multiLapJourneyDetails.clientTxnId value when its get executed**

Comment: What's `nightmare`?

Comment: @Spectric It's likely https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare

Comment: @theusaf Please check again i provided the js

Answer (score 0):

If you have an html page and you put a variable called `v` inside a script block, you can see that variable opening the console and simply writing `v` because your variable is in `window` scope.

Of course you can also add a `console.log(v)` statement in your script block, after the declaration of `v`, in order to see his value automatically when you open the console.

Comment: Can you check question again.Updated .Please

Comment: So you need the value of `this.multiLapJourneyDetails.clientTxnId` printed out in the console?

Comment: @Macro Nisi Exactly what i want.

Comment: Ok, so couldn't you just do something like `console.log(this.multiLapJourneyDetails.clientTxnId)` right after the assignment?

Comment: @Macro Nisi No Its loading from server side i am not pushing it. So i want the value after its loaded in the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Inside the webpage, do `window.myVar = "some value"` instead of `var myVar = "some value"`.

```
nightmare.evaluate(function () {
    return window.myVar;
}).then(function(myVar) {
    // do something here
})
```

Comment: Can you check question again.Updated .Please